# Counting the total number of variable without NA

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with a format of data like this:

```
title,stock1,stock2,stock3
title 1,10,NA,NA
title 2,5,2,3
title3,3,30,NA
```

I would to take the total number of variables which have number. The result should be something like this:

```
title,total_number
title 1,1
title 2,4
title3,2
```

Comment: Try `rowSums(!is.na(df1[,-1]))`  I think the second value should be 3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can check the 'NA' values from column 2 to the last column of the dataset (`!is.na(df1[,-1])`) and use the `rowSums` of that logical matrix to get the 'total_number'

```
data.frame(title=df1$title , total_number =rowSums(!is.na(df1[,-1])))
```